# $\partial (S \cup T) \subset \partial S \cup \partial T$

Tags: real-analysis

$\partial (S \cup T) \subset \partial S \cup \partial T$.

Proof: By definition, $\exists$ an upper and lower neighborhood on both $S \text{ and } T$. Thus, if we take $\partial (S \cup T)$, then $\exists$ two neighborhoods, so there will be two elements in $\partial (S \cup T)$. However, if we take $\partial S \text{ and } \partial T$ independently, then $\exists$ 4 boundary points, including the 2 from $\partial S \cup T$. Hence, $\partial (S \cup T) \subset \partial S \cup \partial T$.

Is it okay to assume there exists two boundary points in a set?

Comment: Your proof is confusing. What are upper/lower neighbourhoods? What does it mean to "take $\partial(S \cup T)$", and "take $\partial S$ and $\partial T$ separately"?

Comment: Also, $[0,\infty) \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ has only one boundary point $\{0\}$.

Comment: I think you assume that $T$ and $S$ are intervals. Is this the case? If not, what are $S$ and $T$? Any subsets of $\mathbb{R}$?